# Converting binary to hex etc. No functions.?

Tags: python, binary, hex, decimal

I need some help converting:

- Binary - hex
- Binary decimal
- Hex - decimal

And vice versa using Python with no use of functions e.g `binascii`

I know a little Python, and I know a bit about arrays. Just can't get my head around this.

Comment: Homework? And do you mean converting *strings* that represent binary, hex, or decimal?

Comment: Yes, sorry converting to strings. Yes, it is homework. Can I get the source code of binascii by any chance?

Comment: Example: user input is 2 prints 00000010 vise versa

Comment: What have you tried? If its homework and you aren't supposed to use any functions, then what you need is a short tutorial on what binary/hex/decimal bases mean. The source code is not exactly going to help you understand this

Comment: It might be helpful to look at pypy's source code (assuming you can't figure it out yourself).

Answer (score 6):

Well, there're built-in casting functions as bin or hex or int, I'm not sure how this will affect your "No use of functions". You can check the following code for them.

```
# Convert decimal to binary
>>> bin(10)
'0b1010'
>>> bin(10)[2:]
'1010'
>>> bin(10)[2:].zfill(8)
'00001010'
# Convert binary to decimal
>>> int('00001010',2)
10
# Convert decimal to hexadecimal
>>> hex(123)
'0x7b'
>>> hex(123)[2:]
'7b'
>>> hex(123)[2:].zfill(8)
'0000007b'
# Convert hexadecimal to decimal
>>> int('0000007b', 16)
123
# Convert binary to hexadecimal
>>> hex(int('1010', 2))
'0xa'
# Convert hexadecimal to binary
>>> bin(int('A', 16))
'0b1010'
```

Edit:

Sample algorithm ..

```
def dec2bin(num):
    if num == 0: return '0'
    bin_str = ''
    while num > 0:
        bin_str = str(num % 2) + bin_str
        num = num / 2
    return bin_str
```

Comment: Thanks but they're still functions though.. Do you know where i can find the source code for these functions e.g bin?

Comment: I don't believe the source code is a big problem. Should you know the basic algorithm if you do the conversions with a pen and paper, it's the same way.
Check my post for sample for dec2bin

Answer (score 0):

Updated without function:

```
>>> for c,i in enumerate(st):
...        a+=i
...        if (c+1)%4==0:
...         print MORSECODEMAP[a]
...         a=''
```

Answer (score -1):

Convrt string to int with base 2 and then to hex

```
>>> hex(int('010110', 2))
>>> '0x16'
>>> hex(int('0000010010001101', 2))
'0x48d'
```

Without functions:

101110101101
For example, to convert 101110101101 to hexadecimal, split it into fours: 
1011 1010 1101
B      A    D
Now map each group to its Morse code..(as folows)

0000    0

0001    1

0010    2

0011    3

0100    4

0101    5

0110    6

0111    7

1000    8

1001    9

1010    A

1011    B

1100    C

1101    D

1110    E

1111    F

Comment: OP wants "no use of functions".

Comment: Ok thanks slowly starting to get it, could you give me one example in python code? ty